# how to use the csv file column headers as fields in a form?

Tags: django, forms, csv

In a form,the user has to upload a csv file and the column headers of the file are used as the fields of the form. Then for each column header a data type is to be selected by the user from a drop down list. I've tried using django but was unsuccessful.What is the best approach?

Comment: show what you have tried

Comment: I've created a basic django form with the django model having 2 fields.But what i have to do is that the fields will be variable according to the csv file uploaded by the user.So i am unable to understand how to appoach the problem.